# Item selected in QTableView does not show the correct background color (Qt 5 vs Qt 6)

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a `QListView` which is styled so that items have a margin around them. When an item is selected, only the item itself (not the margin) changes color. The margins stay transparent (or the background color of the `QListView` itself). See the MWE below.

Now I want to change to a `QTableView` in order to add more columns later on. I want the same behaviour, but notice that the same stylesheet does not achieve the same effect. It shows a bright blue "selection" background around the selected cell (i.e., the "margin" turns blue).

I have noticed that in Qt 6 (specifically Qt 6.4.2 for macOS), the issue does not exist. The `QTableView` acts exactly the same as `QListView` there. However, due to package compatibility issues, I have to use Qt5 (specifically Qt 5.15.2 for macOS). Therefore, I think this is a bug that was fixed in the newer Qt version.

Is there a way to work around this issue, showing the table cell to be transparent?

Here is the `mainwindow.cpp` for a MWE. The `mainwindow.ui` contains two view elements (`listView` and `tableView`), which for ease of demonstration are populated using the same `QStringListModel`.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QStringListModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Create and populate the model, and link it to both views
    QStringListModel *strmodel = new QStringListModel(this);
    QStringList list;
    list << "Item 1" << "Item 2" << "Item 3" << "Item 4" << "Item 5";
    strmodel->setStringList(list);
    ui->listView->setModel(strmodel);
    ui->tableView->setModel(strmodel);

    // Set identical stylesheets for both views
    ui->listView->setStyleSheet("QListView::item {margin: 5px;}"
                                "QListView::item:selected {background-color: red;}");
    ui->tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item {spacing: 5px;}"
                                 "QTableView::item:selected {background-color: red;}");

    //Remove headers and grid from QTableView in order to make it look like the QListView
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->hide();
    ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->hide();
    ui->tableView->setShowGrid(false);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```